# authenticate with cognito from java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using the java sdk to authenticate myself using cognito but at the time of using the ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH type it throws me the following error

my code

String PerformSRPAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        String authresult = null;

```
    AdminInitiateAuthRequest initiateAuthRequest = initiateUserSrpAuthRequest(username,password);
    try {

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxM6ZEVLVF", "xxxxx+4t7NgpkRycoGbnXDu9wlZ");

        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoIdentityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(this.region))

                .build();

        AdminInitiateAuthResult initiateAuthResult = cognitoIdentityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(initiateAuthRequest);

        RespondToAuthChallengeRequest challengeRequest = helper.userSrpAuthRequest(initiateAuthResult, password);
        RespondToAuthChallengeResult result = cognitoIdentityProvider.respondToAuthChallenge(challengeRequest);
        //System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(CognitoJWTParser.getPayload(result.getAuthenticationResult().getIdToken()));
        authresult = result.getAuthenticationResult().getIdToken();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

    return authresult;
}
```

private AdminInitiateAuthRequest initiateUserSrpAuthRequest(String username,String password) {

```
    AdminInitiateAuthRequest initiateAuthRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest();
    initiateAuthRequest.setAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH);
    initiateAuthRequest.setClientId(this.clientId);
      initiateAuthRequest.setUserPoolId(this.userPoolID);
    //Only to be used if the pool contains the secret key.
    //initiateAuthRequest.addAuthParametersEntry("SECRET_HASH", this.calculateSecretHash(this.clientId,this.secretKey,username));
    initiateAuthRequest.addAuthParametersEntry("USERNAME", username);
    initiateAuthRequest.addAuthParametersEntry("PASSWORD", password);
    initiateAuthRequest.addAuthParametersEntry("SRP_A", helper.getA().toString(16));
    return initiateAuthRequest;
}
```

com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unable to verify secret hash for client xxxxxxxxxx (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: e7ad165b-3087-4cc5-9ee9-55c42ed3bf02)